# Google maps not loading over https on Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-maps-api-3, https

We are trying to access Google Maps over HTTPS.

We modified the script on the JSP to

```
script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=<xxxx>&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"
```

This seems to work properly in Chrome and IE8. But in Firefox(V 19.0.2 and 11), there are some issues.

Specifically, We are getting

> TypeError: google.maps.InfoWindow is not a constructor

in the Firefox console which I think means that the Google APIs are not getting accessed properly.

Any suggestions/solutions for this issue?

**More:**

We are getting a 407 response from googlemaps apis.
Specifically, using Fiddler the Request looks like:

```
CONNECT maps.googleapis.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: maps.googleapis.com
```

and the Response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 04:46:47 GMT
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Via: 1.1 XXXXX
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="Websense Content Gateway"
Content-Length: 322
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn.. Its an issue with my company's internet proxy!! I had to add an exception to all the URLs used by my application(including google map apis) and it works fine.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, would you mind posting what urls you added exceptions too?

Answer (score -1):

Add all urls of google map api over https in Location input bar for certificate exceptions.

for example:
https://maps.googleapis.com
https://maps.gstatic.com

'Get Certificate' then 'Confirm Security Exception'
Tools > Advanced > Certificates > View Certificates > 'Servers' Tab > 'Add Exception...'