# javascript in xsl for generating Google Maps from xml files

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT to transform XML files into HTML.

The XML files have information about spatial coordinates, so I want to use them to generate a Map using the Google Maps API.

In order to do this, I codified a javascript and I embedded it into my XSLT. This code works fine in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome but **it's not working** in Mozilla **Firefox** and I can't found the reason...

The Javascript is this:

```
<script><![CDATA[ 
    function LoadMap(div_map, szminx, szmaxx, szminy, szmaxy) {
        var minx, maxx, miny, maxy;

        minx=parseFloat(szminx);
        maxx=parseFloat(szmaxx);
        miny=parseFloat(szminy);
        maxy=parseFloat(szmaxy);

        if (GBrowserIsCompatible() && !isNaN(minx) && !isNaN(maxx) && !isNaN(miny) && !isNaN(maxy)) {
            var d;
            var zoomLevel;              
            var mapSize = new google.maps.Size(250,250, "px", "px");

            var centreX = minx+(maxx-minx)/2;
            var centreY = miny+(maxy-miny)/2;

            var map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById(div_map), {draggableCursor:"crosshair", size:mapSize});
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centreY,centreX));
            map.addControl(new google.maps.SmallMapControl());

            d=maxx-minx;
            if (d<maxy-miny) {d=maxy-miny;}

            if (d<0.0000001) {d=360;}

            zoomLevel=parseInt(-Math.log(d)/Math.log(2)+8);     

            map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
        }
    }
]]></script>
```

And I'm calling it in the XSLT with these lines:

```
...
<td width="250px">
    <div id="map" style="width:250px; height:250px; display:block;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> LoadMap("map", 
        <xsl:value-of select="west/coord"/>, 
        <xsl:value-of select="east/coord"/>, 
        <xsl:value-of select="south/coord"/>,
        <xsl:value-of select="north/coord"/>);
    </script>
</td>
...
```

ideas?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be in the part of the XSLT where the google API is added.
In my XSLT it is embedded like this:

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;hl=ca&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=myKey" type="text/javascript"/>
```

And as I said, it works well in Chrome and IE

If I put the javascript in an static HTML, I have to modify this line moving the sensor=false as described in the google API web page:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=myKey&sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
```

With these modifications the code runs well in all browsers, but this change is not admited by the XSLT. If I add this version of the line in my XSLT all browsers returns this error:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
pointing at the sensor=false position.

Comment: 'not working' means ... ?

Comment: Not working means that the map is not showing in Firefox. The console shows this:  InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.  
TypeError: google.maps.Size is not a constructor.

Comment: I would suggest to first try whether you Javascript code works with Mozilla in a static HTML document. If that works but it does not work when you generate the HTML with XSLT then we need to look at it in the context of XSLT. But currently with the error thrown on `new google.maps.Size(250,250, "px", "px")` it looks to be a pure Javascript problem or embedding problem of the Google maps API and the XSLT you have posted just complicates things for us to find the error. Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056065/google-maps-not-loading-over-https-on-firefox.

Comment: Also consider to show us where/how you include the script element(s) loading the maps API library.

Comment: @Martin Honnen The JavaScript is working well in Firefox, IE and Chrome in an static HTML. It seems that the problem is the script for loading the google API.  I'm editing my question to explain what I have discovered.

Comment: Check whether the Google API code you include does `document.write` or `document.writeln` to output HTML elements, for instance to load further `script` code. Unfortunately the way XSLT is implemented in Mozilla (it renders the result tree of the XSLT transformation) `document.write` is not supported. There is no easy workaround, other than to patch the library to not use the DOM0 `document.write` but to rather create and insert new elements with `document.createElement/node.appendChild`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to escape that last ampersand before `sensor=true` - so **&sensor** should be **&amp;sensor**, like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=myKey&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
```

Makes sense for that error, too.

Comment: Yes, that's the first I thought, but if I make that change the result is the same, the Google API works in IE and Chrome but not in FireFox. However, if you take a look to the API documentation, that is the way documented to call the Google Maps API. I think the last comment of @Martin_Honnen is the right clue to follow and maybe a possible solution is this: https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/2185400